# Redirect if a cookie is set, stay on current page if not

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

I am inexperienced and trying to fumble through this... sorry...

When visitors go to index.php, I need a cookie set just to show they've been there before.  Then when they return again to index.php, I want them redirected to indexreturn.php .  There may be a simpler way to do this, but basically I need return visitors to get a different page.

With the code I have, the redirect happens every time, but when I go into my browser settings to delete specific cookies, I don't see if in there?  Again, sorry if this is a dumb question.

Here's what I have, at the very top of my code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['return']))
{
    header('Location: 

http://www.bloodsugarsecretsexposed.com/special/vsl/indexreturn.php');
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<?php
$cookie_name = "return";
setcookie('return', time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your initial if statement you are asking "if not-set" via !isset, so the user is redirected every time without ever getting the cookie set. Try removing the exclamation point...so "if isset then redirect"

Comment: Thanks!  That solves the problem of why the redirect works even when the cookie is not being set.  Now the redirect doesn't happen, but the cookie still isn't set....  Any idea why?

Comment: The word 'return' is a reserved word in php (and many languages). Not sure if using it as a string effects that. Try using a different cookie name.

Comment: You have to set a cookie before any output goes to the browser (even white space). So put the setcookie immediately after the closing curly brace of the isset test of the cookie (or better yet, make it an if-then statement. So...first you test if the cookie is set, if true, redirect, else, set the cookie. That should do it.

Comment: argh... it is still not working.  I changed the name of the cookie, and I even took out the whole retargeting part and am just trying to successfully set the cookie.  This seems like it should not be so hard :(

Comment: When you set a cookie it is not available on the same page/reload as it was set. Make sure to reload/refresh the page again to see that he cookie had set.

Answer (score 0):

Know this is old question, but seems pretty useful as it was asked in a classroom today.

There are a few issues with your code.

1) As pointed out by @dmayo, you should remove ! isset and NOT use "return" for your cookie name. Return is used/reserved by PHP and can trigger error.

2) Your setcookie string is not correct and will work like this:

```
setcookie('doreturn', 'value', time() + (86400 * 30), "/");  // 86400 = 1 day
```

The entire code I tested (in PHP 7.2) and works:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['doreturn']))
{
    header('Location: index-return.php');
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<?php
$cookie_name = "doreturn";
setcookie('doreturn', 'value', time() + (86400 * 30), "/");  // 86400 = 1 day
?>
```

Or as @dmayo also pointed out, could be written like this and actually cleaner:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['doreturn']))
{
    header('Location: index-return.php');
    exit;
}
$cookie_name = "doreturn";
setcookie('doreturn', 'value', time() + (86400 * 30), "/");  // 86400 = 1 day
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<p>Cookie has been set, reload page to test...</p>
```

Maybe this will help someone else:)

Comment: For some reason I am getting an error when using this method. "This page isn't redirecting properly" ..
`if (isset($_COOKIE['donate-splash']))
{
    header('Location: /index-donate.php');
    exit;
}
else {
$cookie_name = "donate-splash";
setcookie('donate-splash', 'value', time() + (86400 * 30), "/");  // 86400 = 1 day 
}`

Comment: Basically trying to check if cookie is set. If not, then I need to redirect to the "index-donate.php" page AND set the appropriate cookie for 1 day. What am I missing ??

Comment: I would suggest opening your own question. No way anyone can help with "getting a error". Kind of like telling the doctor your body hurts:) Provide the code you are using and detail the "error" you are getting.